# Cannot Serialize a List<> of DynamicProxy2-generated objects with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm running into an issue using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize a `List<T>` of proxied objects.  It works fine with a single proxied object, but the List makes it blow up.  Something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;

[DataContract] 
public class SimpleViewModel 
{ 
    [DataMember] 
    public virtual int ID { get; set; } 
} 
[Test] 
public void TestSerializeArray() 
{ 
    // Generates a proxy of type "SimpleViewModelProxy"
    var proxyModel = (new ProxyGenerator()).CreateClassProxy<SimpleViewModel>(); 
    proxyModel.ID = 1; 
    //Put it into List<> (it can handle a single item without issue!) 
    var list = new List<SimpleViewModel> { proxyModel }; 
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<SimpleViewModel>)); 
    using (var stringWriter = new MemoryStream()) 
    { 
        serializer.WriteObject(stringWriter, list); //BOOM CRASH! 
    } 
}
```

Doing this gives me the following exception:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   : Type 
>   'Castle.Proxies.SimpleViewModelProxy'
>   with data contract name 
>   'SimpleViewModelProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/
>   Castle.Proxies' is not expected.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver 
>   or add any types not known statically
>   to the list of known types - for 
>   example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them  to the list of known
>   types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

I'm able to serialize either a single "SimpleViewModelProxy" object, or a `List<SimpleViewModel>`, but not a `List<SimpleViewModelProxy>`.  Has anyone had any experience getting this to work?  Can they provide some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the type of the proxy to the list of known types:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(
    typeof(List<SimpleViewModel>),
    new[] { proxyModel.GetType() });
```

Comment: This answers my simpler issue.  Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the serializer in my real project -- it's abstracted away by OpenRasta.  But this should get me going in the right direction, thanks.